# Freebsd: backing up dotfiles with a shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, freebsd

A simple shell script is needed to copy dotfiles, adding a **.backup** extension, i.e., **.dotfile1.backup**. The script below will not work because it adds extensions to pre-existing backups forever and ever, i.e., **.dotfile1.backup.backup**.

**bkdot.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in .*; do
    cp “./$file” “./$file.backup”
done
```

The next script seems like it should solve the problem, but nothing happens at all. What is it missing?

**bkdot_revised.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in .*; do
     if [ ! “./$file.backup” ]; then
         cp “./$file” “./$file.backup”
     fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test `[` doesn't have enough information. You need to compare `$file` to a reference. You current construct says "if not this string", but you need to say "if x is not this string". I would use a regex, i.e. with `[[` instead of `[`. Hence,

```
#!/bin/bash
GLOBIGNORE=.:..
for file in .*; do
     if [[ ! "$file" =~ \.backup$ ]]; then
         cp "$file" "$file.backup"
     fi
done
```

- As per Kusalananda's comment, I moved the shebang to `/bin/bash`, to ensure the `[[` construct works.
- As per Gordon Davisson's comment, I added the `GLOBIGNORE`, so that the script doesn't attempt to copy `.` and `..`

A few other things:

- `./` in the paths is unnecessary. You are already in this directory!
- I'm not sure if it was just a copy-paste issue, but you had `“` instead of `"`.
- Personally, I would just copy into another directory, and avoid all these issues, and avoid polluting my home directory. Actually, I would just (incrementally) backup everything instead!

---

Here is a pure `/bin/sh` version. Instead of using the `[[` bashism, I've used [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23472637/1944384) instead.

```
#!/bin/sh
GLOBIGNORE=.:..
for file in .*; do
  case "$file" in
    *.backup) ;;
    *) cp "$file" "$file.backup";;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Also, this will try to back up `.` (the entire current directory) and `..` (its parent), along with any dot directories (e.g. `.ssh`)... but fail because `cp` requires the `-R` option to do this.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Good point. I was actually testing with `zsh`, silly me. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks. Edited. Yeah, I interpreted the test in the question as looking for the current filename's suffix, rather than testing for a copy of the current file + `.backup`. It's a bit unclear, but if there were `.foo`, then `.foo.backup` were created, then `.foo` deleted, `-f` would result in `.foo.backup.backup` being created… which I assume is not preferred.

Comment: It’s not a bash script

Comment: @justinnoor.io What do you mean? This *is* a bash script. Or are you saying that you do not want a bash script? Your shebang refers to `/bin/sh`, but depending on the system, this can be ambiguous. On my system (Arch Linux), if I change the shebang to `/bin/sh`, my script still works. It may well work on yours too.

Comment: I’m on Freebsd. Bash is not part of the base system, and will not be installed. Thanks.

Comment: @justinnoor.io I've edited to avoid bashisms.

Comment: @justinnoor.io Did my edits help solve your problem?

Comment: @Sparhawk Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1):

The `!` operator just negates it's operand so the condition always evaluates to `false`.
There are file test operators, `-f` for instance that returns true if file exists.

However I'm not sure you are doing this right, neither only making backup if it doesn't exist nor always overwriting existing backups is secure.

Could do this way.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in .*; do
     if [ ! -f "./${file}.backup" ]; then
         cp "./${file}" "./${file}.backup"
     fi
done
```

Comment: This doesn’t solve the .backup.backup issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't we simply use `sed` to backup?

```
sed -i.bak 's#\n#\n#' <filepattern*>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intended behavior is:

- create copy of existing dotfiles
- but only if they do not exist

then maybe you could use find:

```
gunhed@gstation:[~/test]0$ ls -la
insgesamt 2
drwxrwxr-x   2 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:45 .
drwxr-x--- 100 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:44 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:39 .test
-rw-rw-r--   1 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:39 .test2
-rw-rw-r--   1 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:39 .test3
-rw-rw-r--   1 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:39 .test4
gunhed@gstation:[~/test]0$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex "^.*[^.bak]$" -exec cp -vn {} {}.bak \;
'./.test4' -> './.test4.bak'
'./.test3' -> './.test3.bak'
'./.test' -> './.test.bak'
'./.test2' -> './.test2.bak'
gunhed@gstation:[~/test]0$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex "^.*[^.bak]$" -exec cp -vn {} {}.bak \;
gunhed@gstation:[~/test]0$ ls -la
insgesamt 4
drwxrwxr-x   2 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:45 .
drwxr-x--- 100 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:44 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:39 .test
-rw-rw-r--   1 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:39 .test2
-rw-rw-r--   1 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:45 .test2.bak
-rw-rw-r--   1 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:39 .test3
-rw-rw-r--   1 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:45 .test3.bak
-rw-rw-r--   1 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:39 .test4
-rw-rw-r--   1 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:45 .test4.bak
-rw-rw-r--   1 gunhed gunhed 0 Dez 30 20:45 .test.bak
gunhed@gstation:[~/test]0$
```

find options used:

- .: use the current directory as starting point
- -maxdepth: do not traverse into subdirs from here
- -type f: find only regular files
- -regex "^.*[^.bak]$": all filenames starting with "."  but NOT ending with .bak (the backup extension in this example)
- -exec cp -vn: cp standard copy command, -n do not overwrite, -v verbose
- {} {}.bak: gets expanded by find to the currently found filename

Maybe this is an alternative way to go. Hopefully not too cryptic. Find helps in many cases ;-)